# I need to send the data from input form from one component to another in React.js. I am doing it with usecontext. But I am facing some issues

Tags: reactjs

I need to send the data from the form that the user will enter from one component to another in React.js. I am doing it with usecontext but the issue is It also Renders the child component on the same page as the parent component also data is sent from the parent component but it's not received in the child component. How can I resolve this?

This is the code of my parent component

```
const data = [firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword];

const FirstPage = () => {
return (<><DataContext.Provider value={data}>
<SecondPage />
);
};
```

using this also Renders the child component on the same page as the parent component

```
<div>
</div>
</DataContext.Provider>
</>
```

> Following code is of DataContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const DataContext = createContext();
export default DataContext;
```

The following code is of the child component

```
const data = useContext  (DataContext);
```

here data is undefined I don't know why